# problem with drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to accomplish an pretty easy drag and drop but it doesn't work for me the code its fine. What i'm doing wrong.
[here's my example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8hjp/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have inconsistencies with your markup and jquery selectors.

You are referencing `$("#pool")` but in your drop html you have the id as `"drop"`